# Segmentation fault on two dimensional vector

Tags: c++11, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a file that contains values in a table format. The number of rows and columns in the file may vary.

```
33829731.00 -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00
205282038.00    -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00
3021548.00  -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00
203294496.00    -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00
205420417.00    -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00   -1.00
```

I am using a two dimensional vector to store the data using the following code.

```
ifstream inputCent("file.txt");

std::vector<std::vector<double> > C;
std::vector<double> col(15);

while(!inputCent.eof())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++)
    {
        inputCent >> col[i];
        C[i].push_back(col[i]);
    }
}
```

But this is giving me `Segmentation fault: 11`. However if I initialize `std::vector<std::vector<double> > C(15);` like this then it works for 15 rows. But as I said the number of rows may vary. Why do I have to initialize the size of `C`? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to `push_back` to a vector that may not exist... The correct code is below:

```
ifstream inputCent("file.txt");

std::vector<std::vector<double> > C;
std::vector<double> col(15);

while(!inputCent.eof())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++)
    {
        inputCent >> col[i];  
    }
    C.push_back(col);
}
```

As shown above, it makes more sense to populate your `col` vector with values before pushing the **entire** `col` vector to the back of `C`.

Comment: Got it, Thanks. :) Silly mistake.